# Unexpected TCP Dup ACK

Tags: tcp

I write a simple TCP server and client myself. After I run them on localhost, I can always capture 'Dup ACK' by Wireshark.

2147 is the Dup ACK. The server port is 12093.

Can anyone tell me why this Dup Ack happens?

```
690 54.831381000    127.0.0.1   127.0.0.1   TCP 68  62301→12093 [SYN] Seq=0 Win=65535 Len=0 MSS=16344 WS=32 TSval=418815085 TSecr=0 SACK_PERM=1
691 54.831549000    127.0.0.1   127.0.0.1   TCP 68  12093→62301 [SYN, ACK] Seq=0 Ack=1 Win=65535 Len=0 MSS=16344 WS=32 TSval=418815085 TSecr=418815085 SACK_PERM=1
692 54.831558000    127.0.0.1   127.0.0.1   TCP 56  62301→12093 [ACK] Seq=1 Ack=1 Win=408288 Len=0 TSval=418815085 TSecr=418815085
693 54.831564000    127.0.0.1   127.0.0.1   TCP 56  [TCP Window Update] 12093→62301 [ACK] Seq=1 Ack=1 Win=408288 Len=0 TSval=418815085 TSecr=418815085
694 54.831652000    127.0.0.1   127.0.0.1   TCP 112 62301→12093 [PSH, ACK] Seq=1 Ack=1 Win=408288 Len=56 TSval=418815085 TSecr=418815085
695 54.831663000    127.0.0.1   127.0.0.1   TCP 56  12093→62301 [ACK] Seq=1 Ack=57 Win=408224 Len=0 TSval=418815085 TSecr=418815085
2140    60.517240000    127.0.0.1   127.0.0.1   TCP 59  12093→62301 [PSH, ACK] Seq=1 Ack=57 Win=408224 Len=3 TSval=418820717 TSecr=418815085
2142    60.517260000    127.0.0.1   127.0.0.1   TCP 56  62301→12093 [ACK] Seq=57 Ack=4 Win=408288 Len=0 TSval=418820717 TSecr=418820717
2145    60.517377000    127.0.0.1   127.0.0.1   TCP 56  62301→12093 [FIN, ACK] Seq=57 Ack=4 Win=408288 Len=0 TSval=418820717 TSecr=418820717
"2146","60.517394000","127.0.0.1","127.0.0.1","TCP","56","12093→62301 [ACK] Seq=4 Ack=58 Win=408224 Len=0 TSval=418820717 TSecr=418820717"
2147    60.517401000    127.0.0.1   127.0.0.1   TCP 56  [TCP Dup ACK 2145#1] 62301→12093 [ACK] Seq=58 Ack=4 Win=408288 Len=0 TSval=418820717 TSecr=418820717
2152    60.517682000    127.0.0.1   127.0.0.1   TCP 56  12093→62301 [FIN, ACK] Seq=4 Ack=58 Win=408224 Len=0 TSval=418820717 TSecr=418820717
2153    60.517704000    127.0.0.1   127.0.0.1   TCP 56  62301→12093 [ACK] Seq=58 Ack=5 Win=408288 Len=0 TSval=418820717 TSecr=418820717
```

Comment: It's updating the receive window size from 408224 to 408288.

Comment: Sorry I didn't get it. In my understanding, 2145, 2152 and 2153 is enough for tcp four wave. then why 2146 and 2147 appear?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by 'TCP four wave', but the duplicate ACKs are updating the receive window size, as I said.

Answer (score 0):

Duplicate ACKs are perfectly normal behaviour as the receiver processes more data and updates its window size. Basically the receiver is saying to its peer: "hey, I know you haven't sent me anything new but when you do I've got more space available now so feel free to send me up to 408288 bytes".